# git differ logs between two branches

Tags: git, gitk

I have created a test git project to figure out how should I get the differ logs between two branches.

In most case, we will have such a case: branch master has cherry-picked some commits to master,see below graph:
[image]

The "I" commit is cherry-picked to master branch. My expected result of differ logs between master and dbg_feature should be "J" only.

But actually, when I run below command:

```
git cherry -v master dbg_feature
```

I will get "I" and "J", the cherry-picked one "I" still list in it:

```
+ a1915061be2f445d322abc7bfb7d19bbb357b917 I
+ 6486e899e07b6d6f539cbcad10655dcc345f434d J
```

If I run below command:

```
git log --oneline --no-merges master..dbg_feature
```

the output is below:

```
6486e89 J
a191506 I
```

If run git rev-list command as below:

```
git rev-list --oneline --no-merges --cherry-pick --right-only master...dbg_feature
6486e89 J
a191506 I
```

Result seems the same as git log.

So what's the right command to get the exact differ logs between this two branches?

Comment: cherry-pick commits will be treated as a new commit, so I think it's impossible to get such a differ to filter out the cherry-picked commits. if everything is merged, it should be fine.

Comment: A bit strange, according to the output, "I" and "J" should be commits of dbg_feature but not of master. Besides, master does not have any equivalent commits to I or J. If it has an equivalent commit to I, the + should be -.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yeah, because I has been cherry-picked to master but that command seems don't know it.

Comment: The two-dot syntax `master..dbg_feature` is limited to acting on the commit graph.  It *does not* examine the *contents* of commits; it looks only at the graph.  See my answer below for modifiers that *do* examine contents of commits.  They should generally be applied only after using a symmetric difference (three-dot syntax) to do graph operations that select commits that are on either the left or right sides, but not common to both.

Comment: Was there any conflict when cherry-picking "I" from dbg_feature to master? Make a patch of I in dbg_feature and a patch of I in master, and check if the 2 patches are equivalent.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, when cherry-pick I to master, there has conflict,after resolve the conflict, then do the cheery-pick.Does that means it's a new commits so can not say it's "I"?

Comment: @lucky1928 Yes, in most cases the conflict-resolved commit is not equivalent any more. Maybe it still is if a recursive strategy with a `theirs` option is used but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ElpieKay Just try to cheery-pick a no conflict commits (add a new file only). it seems behavior the same, so it doesn't matter conflict or it, cherry-pick will always get a new commit.

Comment: @lucky1928 still "+ sha1"? I think it should be "- sha1" if a non conflict cherry-pick is made.

Comment: If you had to resolve a conflict during cherry-picking, the new commit *will not be patch-equivalent* to the original commit.  To see this for yourself, run `git show` on the two commits and compare the diffs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "differ commits".  However, your mention of using `git cherry` suggests that you are talking about what [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) refers to as "equivalent" or "patch-equivalent" commits (or their opposite, which I and they call "inequivalent" commits):

> `--cherry-mark`
>
> Like `--cherry-pick` (see below) but mark equivalent commits with `=` rather than omitting them, and inequivalent ones with `+`.
>
> `--cherry-pick`
>
> Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the “other side” when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.
>
> For example, if you have two branches, `A` and `B`, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with `--left-right` (see the example below in the description of the `--left-right` option). However, it shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, “3rd on b” may be cherry-picked from branch `A`). With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.
>
> `--left-only`
>   `--right-only`
>
> List only commits on the respective side of a symmetric range, i.e. only those which would be marked `<` resp.`>` by `--left-right`.
>
> For example, `--cherry-pick --right-only A...B` omits those commits from `B` which are in `A` or are patch-equivalent to a commit in `A`. In other words, this lists the `+` commits from `git cherry A B`. More precisely, `--cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges` gives the exact list.
>
> `--cherry`
>
> A synonym for `--right-only --cherry-mark --no-merges`; useful to limit the output to the commits on our side and mark those that have been applied to the other side of a forked history with `git log --cherry upstream...mybranch`, similar to `git cherry upstream mybranch`.

Again, all of these are arguments to the `git rev-list` command.  Since `git rev-list` and `git log` are pretty much the same command (except for minor details like their output format :-) ), they work with `git log` as well.

Comment: Maybe differ logs is more meaningful? Updated. Command "git rev-list --oneline --no-merges --cherry master..dbg_feature" seems output the same. I and J but not J only.

Comment: My stumbling block is the word "differ". This is an English word, but as a word, it is a verb: Fred and Bob differ, while Bob and Carol agree. (See http://www.dictionary.com/browse/differ) Saying "logs differ" would mean, for instance, that you ran `git log A` and `git log B` and got different output, which is not surprising but seems to have nothing to do with your actual question.  Meanwhile, note the *important note* that these `rev-list` flags are to be used with the *three* dot syntax.